# images of html page is not zooming in google chrome

Tags: php, html

Please tell me how to work properly zooming of images in html page in google chrome it is running well in mozilla firefox. i simply tried img tag without any css

```
<?php 
    for($i=1;$i<count($path);$i++)
    {
        echo '<img src="'.$path[$i].'" id='.$i.$i.' style="position:absolute; left:'.$x[$i].'px; top:'.$y[$i].'px; visibility:hidden" />';
    }
?>
```

Comment: by `zooming` you mean when you resize browser to a narrower size the image will become smaller accordingly?

Comment: yes it should work properly

Answer (score 0):

You are using CSS. Inline CSS but still CSS. Why are your images set to hidden (visibility attribute) ?

Comment: because my requirement is that when i clicked on button then that image is displayed otherwise not

Comment: Well, OK.
Can you post your generated HTML source code and the CSS coming with it ?